# Swift about a function as other function's return value;

Tags: swift

Look,

[image]

function num's return value is function number,and function number's return value is a Int value ,so if function num's return value is a function who's return value is void ,what I write? if use

[image]

and the function num's return value is a tuple type,so what so I do? thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment what you have is a function with a function nested inside it that can only be called from within the outer function. If you want to return a function that will add two Int values together then you need to return a closure like so:

```
func num() -> (Int,Int) -> Int {
    let number = {
        (a:Int, b: Int) in
            return a + b
    }
    return number
}

let aNum = num()
aNum(1,2) // 3
```